# How to add any symbols after prefix_?

Tags: dictionary, flutter

is there any solution? e.g. I have data in Map with key **favorites_** prefix and values **_suffix** (for example: **favorites_jeans, favorites_suit,...,**). I want to by dint of loop get that values and set in `List`, because of it I must give keys of map, right? 
I want to know how can I get values of `myMap["favorites_*"]` (* - after the favorites_ any symbols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<String> favoritesStrings = ['favorite_name','favorite_jeans',];
  Map<String,dynamic> myMap = {
    favoritesStrings[0]:'0',
    favoritesStrings[1]:'1',
    'someKey':'2',
    'anotherKey':'3',
  };
  favoritesStrings.forEach((favorite)=>print(myMap[favorite]));//prints 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As per what I understood, you want to fetch value from map using "favorites_" + a dynamic value from list as key.

You just have to use String templates and use **$** to insert suffix variable to build key dynamically:

```
List<String> suffixList = ["jeans", "suit", "shirt"];

for(String suffix in suffixList) {
  var item = myMap["favorites_$suffix"];
  // Do something with item
}
```

Hope it helps